# Design View cannot display because some elements are not built

Tags: winrt-xaml

I accidentally make a global project name change from say Project1 or project2

I have LayoutAwarePage.cs in Common Folder .

The Design view cannot display any page for viewing.

Now all the XAML page contains the following error:

The error:

```
error here:

The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist in the namespace "using:Project_name.Common".
<commom: LayoutAwarePage>




error here : The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible
<Page.Resources>


What is the solution ?
```

Comment: Go change all your references to Project1 to your new Project2.

Comment: it does not help. I had tried many ways. Finally, I had to recreate a new app based on the old app files.